# How to get users created before X months ago?

Tags: mysql

I have `User` table

```
id created_date
1  1583748624
2  1284026797
3  1347185197
```

Here created_date in in `timestamp`.

**How can I retrieve the only users who has been created more than 3 months?**

In other terms, user created_date already passed 3 months from today.

```
SELECT * from User where created_date > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

I tried above. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user
where created_Date < now()-interval 3 month;
```

if unix timestamp needed

```
WHERE user_datecreated < unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ??